# Which topics in pattern recognition a newbie have to pick up first?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, pattern-recognition

Machine Learning is a very wide topic and it is too much for a newbie to learn everything, then start focusing on those relevant to him.

Suppose I am interested in pattern recognition in time-series data. Which topics in machine learning should I pay more attention to?

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/time-series/info) would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All depends on what type of data you would like to perform the pattern recognition in time-series: words/expressions on web, imagery or voice recognition.

I have more experience in the first, and from what I know, the most popular : structural learning algorithms like [CRF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItA3K7i2Pa0), and from the newest - [NuPic](http://numenta.org/) , that is, apparently, very popular also for imagery and voice recognition too.

also check [Convolutional](http://www.wildml.com/2015/11/understanding-convolutional-neural-networks-for-nlp/) and [Recurrent](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/) neural networks for pattern recognition in time-series, that are actively used by giants like Google